# MySQL Auto_Increment trying to automatically insert prior used values

Tags: mysql, delphi, firedac

I Use Delphi 10.2, MySQL.  I have a table that has about 50,000 records and has an Auto_Increment primary key.  It has suddenly, and on it's own with no help from me, started trying to re-insert old key values.  As a matter of fact, it started over with the value 1.  I have no idea how to fix this and I hope you might be able to help.

Thanks,
Jim Sawyer

Comment: This is not possible in MySQL. How do you detect this? error messages, inserted data, etc... Why you decide that this value is generated and is not specified explicitly in INSERT?

Answer (score 2):

If the MySQL table is defined with an auto increment primary key then you should never specify the key value.  MySQL should not re-use old key values, but you may want to check if there is any table corruption.  You can also reset the table's auto-increment value using an ALTER TABLE command.  (There's a tutorial on this here: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-reset-auto-increment)

You can use the Firedac monitoring to confirm whether or not you are sending the primary key to MySQL - set you connection to be monitored using the FireDAC component - they supply a monitoring tool that you can setup to see all of the SQL being transferred.  Normally the Firedac layer would do an insert with no primary key and then use LAST_INSERT_ID to update the TField to have the actual value inserted.

If you are sending the wrong key then alter your logic so you don;t send the primary key on an insert.

Comment: I wasn't  entering the primary key value.  I always permit the computer to do that automatically.  I really think this was corruption of the table.  I finally checked to see what the largest primary key value in the table, then manually entered the next value through the command prompt, then deleted that record.  That reset the primary key to it's proper value and all is now well.  I'm just a bit puzzled why it occurred in the first place.     Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can reset the autoincrement value to any value you want with the following command

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name> AUTO_INCREMENT = <new value>;
```

so if new value is 100, the next inserted record receives a value of 100.